# Sublime text scurly brace shows on next line

Tags: erlang, sublimetext3

Typing { in SublimeText creates a corresponding } on the next line like

{

}

but in preferences, typing { gives {}

How do I get rid of the second line }, either typing it manually or having it on the same line? I'm writing in Erlang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open user settings/preferences and add the line below inside the config json.

```
"auto_match_enabled" : false
```

source: https://superuser.com/a/398387